# JDBC Connection String picking up part of password for host name in SOAPUI

Tags: groovy, database-connection, soapui, ready-api

I am trying to change the connection string dynamically between two different databases (Oracle and Postgres)
So I have a global connection string at project level  like below
[image]

I am trying to set this connectiong string from groovy script for oracle and postgres by building up the connection string

```
if(databaseType.contains("postgre"))
{

   def postgresConnstring=  "jdbc:postgresql://"+databaseHost+":"+databasePort+"/"+databaseUsername+"?user="+databaseUsername+"&password="+databasePassword

  testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.databaseConnectionContainer.getDatabaseConnectionByName('GhixDB').setConnectionString(postgresConnstring)
}

else
 if (databaseType.contains("oracle"))
{ 
    def oracleConnString=  "jdbc:oracle:thin:"+databaseUsername+"/"+databasePassword+"@"+databaseHost+":"+databasePort+":"+databaseSid

    testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.databaseConnectionContainer.getDatabaseConnectionByName('GhixDB').setConnectionString(oracleConnString)


}
```

JDBC Connection String for Oracle is something like below.    jdbc:oracle:thin:${#Project#databaseUserName}/${#Project#databasePassword}@${#Project#databaseHost}:${#Project#databasePort}:${#Project#databaseSid}

So when I set this connection string at project level 
i see that the database configuration is picking up part of password and seeting it in the database host field. like below.

[image]

I see that the password value gets set to PASS_VALUE when we manually set the connection string.
but when I pass some real password value dynamically from script which is more than 10 char long the connection string is picking up the remaining char fro password and passing to the host name.

can someone please help me solve this issue ??

Comment: Please see if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37655778/soapui-ability-to-switch-between-database-connections-for-test-suite/37659250#37659250) approach help you to have better control to switch between databases.

Comment: @Rao The solution mentioned is when we have one database type. But I have two different database types oracle and Postgres. The connection string is different for both the databases.

Comment: You still can use it provided if you can add an addition property for `Driver Class` as well.

Comment: The connection string is different for both the databases. So changing the driver alone would not work.

Comment: Well, one more property to externalise it.

Comment: if I externalize the connection string property, a part of the password is being picked up by the host field .. since password value is usually renamed to PASS_VALUE in the connection string.. when i pass the actual value,, part of the password after 10 char is picked by host,, which is shown in the snapshot that I have attached in the question...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115434/discussion-between-monica-thaneer-and-rao).

Comment: Is it still a problem? Did you make any changes based on the chat discussion?