# How to apply connection settings to all JDBC test steps in SoapUI?

Tags: testing, jdbc, groovy, soapui

## tl;dr

After (manually) having updated the JDBC connection properties of a single SoapUI test step,

- how can I copy them to the other test steps in the project (without resorting to `${property}` expansion)?
- I suppose Groovy is the key?

---

## Background

I have a SoapUI Project containing many JDBC test steps pointing to my development database like that:

> The Open source version of JDBC TestStep has fields for setting the
>   connection properties and the SQL query manually.
>   [Getting Started | JDBC (SoapUI.org)](https://www.soapui.org/jdbc/getting-started.html)

**Constraint:** I am currently working without having the *Connections* feature from Smartbear's Pro version available.

## Goal

Before deploying, I want to run the same tests in our staging environment i.e. I have to *change JDBC connection settings throughout the test suite(s).*

**Preliminary considerations:**
In order to re-direct all JDBC steps to the staging database I could edit my tests to connection string and driver fields relying on property expansion like described in [SOAPUI ability to switch between database connections for test suite](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37659250/828080).

**Specific approach:**
However in this case here, I need to *see the connection strings and drivers directly on the test steps* (in contrast to seeing just the `${expansion}` variables) – **Rationale:** it gives more useful screenshots with the real values ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The connection properties can be copied from one test step to other JDBC test steps in the project using the following Groovy script:

```
// Select "correctly configured" JDBC TestStep/Case/Suite to be used as reference
def s = testRunner.testCase
        .testSuite
        .project
        .testSuites["Reference TestSuite"]
        .testCases["Reference TestCase"].getTestStepAt(1)
log.info "${s.getConnectionString()}, ${s.getDriver()}"

// Use s to configure all JDBC TestSteps in current TestSuite
testRunner.testCase
        .testSuite
        .testCases
        .each{iTC, testCase ->
            //log.debug "${iTC}: ${testCase}"
            testCase.getTestStepsOfType(com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.JdbcRequestTestStep)
                    .each{testStep ->
                        testStep.setConnectionString(s.getConnectionString())
                        testStep.setDriver(s.getDriver())
                        log.info "${testStep.getConnectionString()}, ${testStep.getDriver()}"
                    }
        }
```

To run this, I have introduced an additional test suite `internal TS` and test case `internal TC`, respectively. I have added a Groovy TestStep `copyJdbcSettings` with above script to `internal TC` and executed it once.
I have then disabled `internal TS` until I need it again someday.