# How do i can keep different environments option for SOAP UI PRO?

Tags: soapui, test-environments

I have automated scripts to be run but sometime i need to run in dev environment and than in test environment changing wsdl and jdbc connection manually is tedious task. Is there any way/ options provided by SOAPUI ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SOAPUI ability to switch between database connections for test suite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37655778/soapui-ability-to-switch-between-database-connections-for-test-suite)

Comment: what about wsdl? can you help me like what is the best option to switch environment between DEV  and TEST ?
How can i give preference about which environment i want to use.

Comment: I believe wsdl should be the same irrespective of environment. Isn't it?

Comment: No we have our environments mentioned in wsdl 
for eg:- http://**********test**********?wsdl for Test Env and 
http://**********Dev**********?wsdl for Dev Env
So how can i handle those? i tried using Service Endpoint but while running i need to change for every wsdl and that is tedious thing.

Comment: Looks you are talking about different servers, where endpoint will be different, but not the content of wsdl.

Comment: Hi Rao, No we are using same server but different URLs , the content of wsdl remains same but wsdl is defferent eg :- http://**Test1**?wsdl for Test environment and http://**Dev1**?wsdl for dev environment, whenever i need to run my TC i need to load dev wsdl for dev environment and than test wsdl  for running in test environment.

Comment: Sorry, I am not convinced with your comment. May be you can download both wsdls and compare. You are accessing the wsdl from different servers thats it. More over, functionality should work the same for same operation irrespective of where is hosted, then wsdl should be same.